# Node - wait api call quota without block th thread

Tags: node.js, nonblocking

If i want to call an API many times in a `for` loop and wait a second after each HTTP request how can i do it without using sleep and block the thread?

Comment: `setTimeout`: https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args

Answer (score 0):

Just set interval (https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args):

```
setInterval(() => {
   request.get(...)
}, 1000)
```

P.S. We ignoring responses here.